# java Regex Question

Tags: java

In Java - I need to search/validate an input string for a number or for a specific string. it must be one of them.
For example - If I have this input lines:

```
cccccccc 123 vvvvvvvvv jhdakfksah
cccccccc ABC vvvvvvnhj  yroijpotpo
cccdcdcd 234 vcbvbvbvbv lkjd dfdggf
ccccbvff ABC jflkjlkjlj fgdgfg
```

I need to find 123, ABC, 234, ABC

to look for the number I could use regex: "\d+" but to look for either of them How can I combine them?

Comment: Are the examples "real", or made up? Looks to me like you don't need to use regex at all, but a simple substring operation would be enough...

Answer (score 2):

You can specify alternatives in a regular expression by using the `|` character:

```
\d+|[ABC]+
```

In your specific example, the string you want is seemingly always the second "word" (delimited by a space), so it can be beneficial to include the space in the regular expression to look for it. Either by using a capturing group to capture the part you actually want to extract:

```
" (\d+|[ABC]+)"
```

(I used quotation marks to delimit the regex). Or by using a lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<= )(\d+|[ABC]+)
```

which will only match the desired portion, but still requires the space before it.

Answer (score 2):

As at least one other answer has mentioned, it looks like you're picking out the second word in a space-delimited string, and regular expressions are more work than is necessary for that task. `String.indexOf` would be enough:

```
String line = ...;
int start = line.indexOf(" ") + 1;
int end = line.indexOf(" ", end);
String word2 = line.substring(start, end);
```

or, now that I think about it

```
String word2 = line.split(" ")[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have something like this...

```
^[^ ]* ([^ ]*) .*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: [0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+ or maybe [0-9]+|(ABC)+; not sure what your rule for the characters is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
"(\d+|ABC)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
^\w+\W+(\w+)
```

And make your expression to match the begin of a line with `^`.